# Using a laptop as a server via wifi over a VPN using DHCP

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, wifi, subnet

My application lives on a laptop which will be on the company's wireless network. So what are the limitations because of this? The place I work has a wireless network which is given public access to everyone and to access any of the internal services we need to sign in to the VPN. I heard that some companies have an internal wireless network. How does this work? Is the access password for the wireless network set to the company directory services password?

Also on a slightly different note, if all I have is a DHCP hostname are there any issues I should be aware of if a different machine from inside the network has to talk to it? I mean in terms of subnets, DNS servers etc? I am assuming that if I have the DHCP hostname of machine I will be able to access it from inside the network across all subnets and even if multiple DNS servers need to be pinged. Am I correct?

Comment: this is not a programming-related question. Check www.superuser.com

Answer (score 11):

You had me at the first line - this is an appalling idea.

It's a bad idea to run this sort of thing on laptops.
It's a bad idea to run this sort of thing via wifi.
It's a bad idea to run this sort of thing on behind or even in front of this type of VPN.
It's a bad idea to run this sort of thing on a machine using client side DHCP.

Get the application in a data centre and do a proper design.

Comment: I know this is a horrible idea and should never be done. I just simplified my design problem and presented it in a way that is easy to grasp for everyone by leaving out unnecessary details. I just wanted to discuss was the issues I need to keep in mind given my current scenario. Can you elaborate why all those are bad ideas? May be that is what I am looking for.

Comment: 1) Laptops are fragile, slow and non-resilient, 2) wifi is fragile, slow and non-resilient, 3) this kind of client-facing VPN isn't often designed for handling inward-facing service provision in a robust way and 4) using DHCP for servers isn't a very good ideas ever, that's why sysadmins use statics.

Comment: the man speaketh the truth. This *will* go wrong for you, likely immediately.

Comment: I can't upvote this answer enough.

Answer (score 0):

You have obviously got IT limitation there where you've ran out of options internally to host a server with your application and have no support in doing so.
Look at your design again and have your boss to request the appropriate resources for a proper setup, have him pust your requirements internally.
Either way you can just go and host your own sever from a cloud provider with abit of budget.

Let us know how you get on, but honestly don't wast time trying to host over a laptop!